# OData function parameter type double

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I've created an function that have as parameter `int, int, double`:

```
var functionUnitConvertDouble = builder.Function("Convert");
functionUnitConvertDouble.Parameter<int>("From");
functionUnitConvertDouble.Parameter<int>("To");
functionUnitConvertDouble.Parameter<double>("Value");
functionUnitConvertDouble.Returns<double[]>();
```

and this is the method it's related to:

```
[HttpGet]
[ODataRoute("ConvertUom(From={uomIdFrom},To={uomIdTo},Value={value})")]
public IHttpActionResult ConvertUom([FromODataUri] int uomIdFrom, 
    [FromODataUri] int uomIdTo, [FromODataUri] double value)
{
    // Some stuff here
}
```

Function is okay, and I can call this URL and it works fine.

```
http://localhost:63911/odata/Convert(From=4,To=2,Value=20)
```

However, my last parameter is a double, and when i try to pass a double parameter it does not work (I get an error message like "endpoint not exist"), for example:

```
http://localhost:63911/odata/Convert(From=4,To=2,Value=20.5)
```

Comment: Have you been able to resolve the issue? I have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Since double contain dots and IIS handle dots weirdly (would be the same if it was a string as a parameter), add this to your web.congfig.

```
<system.webServer>
    <!--You might have more stuff here-->

    <modules>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```